# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iloc' in x_test

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Here I have four inputs and I tried to predict the future value. Before that I scaled my inputs data into 0,1. Then I created x_test value.

Then before predict the code I have to write another code to predict my value in every one hour. For that I want to extract into rows in my x_test_n value  . Then I used iloc code. But unfortunately it didn't work because of numpy array. Then I found the code for that and I tried that code , it gave me an error also. Here is my code that I tried,

```
data10 = pd.read_csv('data.csv',"," )
data10 = data10.replace(np.nan, 0)
data10 = pd.DataFrame(data10,columns=['date','x1','x2','x3','x4'])
data10.set_index('date', inplace=True)

data10 = data10.values
X = 1
n_out = 1

 x,y=list(),list()
 start =0



for _ in range(len(data10)):
in_end = start+X
out_end= in_end + n_out
if out_end < len(data10):
    x_input = data10[start:in_end]
    x.append(x_input)
    y.append(data10[in_end:out_end,0])
start +=1
 x = np.asanyarray(x)
 y = np.asanyarray(y)



scaler_x = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range =(0, 1))
x = np.array(x).reshape ((len(x),4 ))
x = scaler_x.fit_transform((x))
scaler_y = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range =(0, 1))
y = np.array(y).reshape ((len(y), 1))
y = scaler_y.fit_transform(y)

train_end = 150
x_test=x[train_end: ,]
y_test=y[train_end:] 
x_test,y_test = np.array(x_test),np.array(y_test)
x_test = np.reshape(x_test,(x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1],1))
```

Then my x_test be like this:

```html
[[[0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 1.4332613e-01 0.0000000e+00]
  [0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 6.8191981e-01]]

 [[0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 6.8191981e-01]
  [0.0000000e+00 1.4034396e-02 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00]]

 [[0.0000000e+00 1.4034396e-02 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00]
  [0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 6.3639030e-02 0.0000000e+00]]
```

After that I want to extract rows in   my x_test_n using iloc

```
filtered_3 = x_test_n
new_df = pd.DataFrame(scaler_x.fit_transform(filtered_3), columns=filtered_3.columns, index=df.index)
```

Then got an error :

```html
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-715b662d895d> in <module>()
    101 
    102 filtered_3 = x_test_n
--> 103 new_df = pd.DataFrame(scaler_x.fit_transform(filtered_3), columns=filtered_3.columns, index=df.index)
    104 # current_calorie = filtered_3.iloc[:,]
    105 # last_calorie_record = 0

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    515         if y is None:
    516             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 517             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    518         else:
    519             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in fit(self, X, y)
    306         # Reset internal state before fitting
    307         self._reset()
--> 308         return self.partial_fit(X, y)
    309 
    310     def partial_fit(self, X, y=None):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in partial_fit(self, X, y)
    332 
    333         X = check_array(X, copy=self.copy, warn_on_dtype=True,
--> 334                         estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
    335 
    336         data_min = np.min(X, axis=0)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    449         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
    450             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."
--> 451                              % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
    452         if force_all_finite:
    453             _assert_all_finite(array)

ValueError: Found array with dim 3. MinMaxScaler expected <= 2.
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Comment: `iloc` is a `pandas` indexing approach, not a `numpy` one.

Comment: @hpaulj yes I know it, I am searching a method to put my np array values into dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If "x_test.shape" is 3d, (3 values in result) you can try code below, else i can look different ways.

```
nsamples, nx, ny = x_test.shape
x_test_reshape = x_test.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))
```

If it works, you can transform your array to dataframe with same way.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, I will try your code and let you know